# a GOOD way to extend the function getAddressesHtmlSelect() in Onepage\Abstract.php

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, development, shipping-address

I want to filter the addresses in the checkout process. For that I have to overwrite the function `getAddressesHtmlSelect()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php`

One way would be: take the file `Abstract.php` out of `core` into `local`. But that is a very dirty way, and I am not sure if I could just take out one file or if I had to take the hole Checkout module into the `local` folder? (that as a small side question)

What I search is a clean and good way to do what I want to do.

Can you lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @Marius: with this method I will destroy the update possibility of this installation, right? Hoped for a better solution to filter the addresses.

Comment: It won't change the required steps for an update, assuming it was a concrete implementation you could rewrite, you'd still be modifying a function which may change, so you'd still need to check after an upgrade, that you haven't lost / broke anything (relying on a function that is removed for example). It's not ideal, but the only other option I can think of would be to rewrite the individual blocks that extend this abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy the file in `local` folder. And, yes, copying just one file works. You need this because the Abstract class is not instantiated, and in Magento you can rewrite using `config.xml` only classes that are instantiated.
[See more words about this here:](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2011/09/why-cant-you-override-some-classes-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the single file over to the local folder. This will be the easiest way of achieving a modification to that function. As somebody who has recently made some modifications to this function I can tell you that there is quite a lot of work involved in doing this the 'correct' way due to the fact that there are quite a few (10 I think) classes that extend this abstract class. Whilst I don't believe the function `getAddressesHtmlSelect` is used by all of them, due to it's dependency on other functions within the class though, you could be jumping into a rabbit hole if you attempt to rewrite all the instances in which it might be used.

Unless you have a specific reason to do this the 'correct' way (distributed module for example). I'd be tempted to take one on the chin and just copy it to local.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do when you say filter. One option would be to change the addresses when they are loaded. I would suggest that you could rewrite the customer model and change the getAddresses function.

```
public function getAddresses()
{
    $this->_addresses = $this->getAddressesCollection()->getItems();
    return $this->_addresses;
}
```

Or maybe even better you could find an appropriate event to observe maybe the collection load after would be a good one for this. But you would have to be careful to only change the addresses when you are in the checkout process.